# Assign smooth-scrollbar.js to wrapper instead of body

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using smooth-scrollbar.js and a custom cursor. Currently smooth-scrollbar.js is assigned to the body which is breaking the cursor (when you scroll down the page the cursor does not move with the page). To fix this I need to assign smooth-scrollbar.js to a wrapper inside of the body and not the body itself. So I have created a wrapper div '.content'. But I can't figure out how to assign smooth-scrollbar.js to it.

[Codepen here](https://codepen.io/gwjr/pen/NWYaBJV/40c5154700d8db2a14990b139e5f6295)

```js
const cursor = document.querySelector('#cursor');
const cursorCircle = cursor.querySelector('.cursor__circle');

const mouse = { x: -100, y: -100 }; // mouse pointer's coordinates
const pos = { x: 0, y: 0 }; // cursor's coordinates
const speed = 0.1; // between 0 and 1

const updateCoordinates = e => {
  mouse.x = e.clientX;
  mouse.y = e.clientY;
}

window.addEventListener('mousemove', updateCoordinates);


function getAngle(diffX, diffY) {
  return Math.atan2(diffY, diffX) * 180 / Math.PI;
}

function getSqueeze(diffX, diffY) {
  const distance = Math.sqrt(
    Math.pow(diffX, 2) + Math.pow(diffY, 2)
  );
  const maxSqueeze = 0.15;
  const accelerator = 1500;
  return Math.min(distance / accelerator, maxSqueeze);
}


const updateCursor = () => {
  const diffX = Math.round(mouse.x - pos.x);
  const diffY = Math.round(mouse.y - pos.y);
  
  pos.x += diffX * speed;
  pos.y += diffY * speed;
  
  const angle = getAngle(diffX, diffY);
  const squeeze = getSqueeze(diffX, diffY);
  
  const scale = 'scale(' + (1 + squeeze) + ', ' + (1 - squeeze) +')';
  const rotate = 'rotate(' + angle +'deg)';
  const translate = 'translate3d(' + pos.x + 'px ,' + pos.y + 'px, 0)';

  cursor.style.transform = translate;
  cursorCircle.style.transform = rotate + scale;
};

function loop() {
  updateCursor();
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

requestAnimationFrame(loop);



const cursorModifiers = document.querySelectorAll('[cursor-class]');

cursorModifiers.forEach(curosrModifier => {
  curosrModifier.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    const className = this.getAttribute('cursor-class');
    cursor.classList.add(className);
  });
  
  curosrModifier.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    const className = this.getAttribute('cursor-class');
    cursor.classList.remove(className);
  });
});

gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

ScrollTrigger.defaults({
  markers: false
});


//smooth scrollbar
var scrollbar = Scrollbar.init(document.body, { delegateTo: document, alwaysShowTracks: false, speed: 0.7, damping:0.1});

ScrollTrigger.scrollerProxy(document.body, {
    scrollTop(value) {
      if (arguments.length) {
        scrollbar.scrollTop = value; 
      }
      return scrollbar.scrollTop; 
    }
});

scrollbar.addListener(ScrollTrigger.update);
ScrollTrigger.defaults({ scroller: document.body });
```

```css
#cursor {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  will-change: transform;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

@media (hover: hover) and (pointer: fine) {
  .cursor__circle {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    margin-top: -50%;
    margin-left: -50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid 1px rgba(227, 222, 193, 0.64);
    transition: opacity 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 1, 0.5, 1),
      background-color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 1, 0.5, 1),
      border-color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 1, 0.5, 1),
      width 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 1, 0.5, 1),
      height 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 1, 0.5, 1);
  }
  
  #cursor.arrow .cursor__circle{
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    background-color: #073099;
    border-color: #073099;
  }
  
  #cursor.arrow::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -50%;
    top: -50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('https://svgshare.com/i/MzQ.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
  }
  
  #cursor.subtle .cursor__circle{
    opacity: 0.16;
  }
  
  #cursor.overlay .cursor__circle{
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    background-color: rgba(227, 222, 193, 0.08);
    border-color: transparent;
  }
}








* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

html,
body,
section{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

section{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

section::after{
  content: 'Only for laptop or desktop ‍♂️';
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #1c213e;
  line-height: 1.7;
}

.container{
  width: 33vw;
}

.image-container{
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75%;
/*   margin-bottom: 0.5vw; */
  margin-top: 10vw;
}

.image-container img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  filter: brightness(95%);
  transition: transform 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.25, 1, 0.5, 1);
}

.text{
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #1c213e;
  line-height: 1.7;
}

.underline{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.underline::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #1c213e;
  opacity: 0.32;
  transition: opacity 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 1, 0.5, 1);
}

.button{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: #1c213e;
}

.button.icon-button{
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: -8px;
}

.info{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

@media (hover: hover) and (pointer: fine) {
  .image-container:hover img{
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  
  .underline:hover::after{
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  section::after{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/smooth-scrollbar/8.7.4/smooth-scrollbar.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gsap@3/dist/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/gsap-latest-beta.min.js"></script>
<div id="cursor">
  <div class="cursor__circle"></div>
</div>

<div class="content">
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="image-container" cursor-class="arrow">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/HDvyzVW/vase-2.jpg" alt="minimalist vase">
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="image-container" cursor-class="arrow">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/HDvyzVW/vase-2.jpg" alt="minimalist vase">
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is interested, the answer is to create a wrapper and put the cursor outside the wrapper

```
<div id="cursor">
  <div class="cursor__circle"></div>
</div>

<div id="scroll-container">
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="image-container" cursor-class="arrow">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/HDvyzVW/vase-2.jpg" alt="minimalist vase">
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="image-container" cursor-class="arrow">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/HDvyzVW/vase-2.jpg" alt="minimalist vase">
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
</div>
```

```
#scroll-container {
  width: 100%;
  height:  100%;
}
```